# Performing a build in VSTS using difference projects / reference DLLs

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, msbuild, projects

Using VSTS.

For our build the first step is to build a load of old VS2005 projects, this works however the next step is to build a project in VS2013. This won't build as it references the DLLs created from the first /old projects, anybody know how to get round this issue, its almost like I need to refresh the VS2013 application to pick up the new references.

:)

Comment: Do you get any warning or error messages during you build this project? Maybe it is related to the .NET Framework version. I mean that your current project uses different .NET Framework version as the reference, so it would have this issue. You could use the same .NET version to compile your two projects, and then test it again.

Comment: @ Martin Cooke,what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?